# Passing the username/password from client to web API using GET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

for example I have a web API : http://example.com/api/product.

I have a C# client to consume this web API. Something like that to get whole list of product.

```
// List all products.
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/products").Result;  // Blocking call!

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

    // Parse the response body. Blocking!
    var products = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().Result;

    foreach (var p in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1};\t{2}", p.Name, p.Price, p.Category);
    }
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```

How do I pass the username and password from C# client to server's API? What I want is when the C# client to get whole product list from web API.

The client will send the username and password to the server's API. if the server's web API checks whether it is authorized user from database, if not don't let it get product list.

Comment: what is the type of the client object?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach in a proof of concept some time ago, I hope it helps you.

I wrote something like this, an "AuthenticationController" with 2 methods:

```
public bool Login(string username, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void Logout()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

The Login method creates a cookie that will be sent to the client; then, in each request, you need to send it back to the server. You can use the [Authorize] attribute in your controller actions to validate allowed roles and rights.

Comment: hi, our web api is for the other company's programmer to integrate our web api to their own program. so we prefer every time when they do the request need they to send username, password.  based on their username ,password we will link them to their database. everycompany has different database.      I thought a way to pass user information  is in the server side control  using get( string name,string password) ; something like that, then in the client ,we can pass userinformation  by uri.    I just want to know wheter there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use have an authentication routine that will assign a token to the client. The client would then cache that token and pass that token in subsequent requests. The authentication routine should be via SSL to prevent sniffing on the wire and shouldn't be stored on the device at all (the token can be cached to the device).

This will give you a fair bit of control over the client. Your service is then in a position where it can preemptively deactivate the client (kill the token and force a re-auth - essentially a timemout situation). You are also in a position to protect your application on the client (if the application is compromised on the device the user credentials won't be passed around).

You could use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) to get you started along this path.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult LogOn(string loginIdentifier)
{
    if (!Identifier.IsValid(loginIdentifier))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("loginIdentifier",
                    "The specified login identifier is invalid");
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(
            Identifier.Parse(loginIdentifier));

        // Require some additional data
        request.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest
        {
            BirthDate = DemandLevel.NoRequest,
            Email = DemandLevel.Require,
            FullName = DemandLevel.Require
        });

        return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
    }
}
```

Source: [Sample Code](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/programmatic-openid-relying-party/)